# hotcakecommerce custom payment method doesnt work

Tags: asp.net, e-commerce, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

i have implement all method for custome payment method , upload dll file to bin folder and check payment method in admin panel . paymet method appear in chekcout page but no one of my custom payment doesnt run . is there any full source of custom payment method in hotcakecommerce? 
workfolw :

```
public class StartMyPaymentMethodCheckout : ThirdPartyCheckoutOrderTask
{
    public override string PaymentMethodId
    {
        get { return MyPaymentMethod.Id(); }
    }

    public override bool ProcessCheckout(OrderTaskContext context)
    {

        if (context.HccApp.CurrentRequestContext.RoutingContext.HttpContext != null)
        {
            try
            {
                MyPaymentMethodSettings settings = new MyPaymentMethodSettings();
                var methodSettings = context.HccApp.CurrentStore.Settings.MethodSettingsGet(PaymentMethodId);
                settings.Merge(methodSettings);

                // Here you can do custom processing of your payment.

                // It can be direct post to payment service or redirection to hosted payment page
                // In either case you have to end up on HccUrlBuilder.RouteHccUrl(HccRoute.ThirdPartyPayment) page
                // So either you have to do such redirect here on your own
                // or make sure that third party hosted pay page will make it in case of successfull or failed payment

                HttpContextBase httpContext = new HccHttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
                httpContext.Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                EventLog.LogEvent("My Custom Checkout", "Exception occurred during call to Moneris: " + ex.ToString(), EventLogSeverity.Error);
                context.Errors.Add(new WorkflowMessage("My Custom Checkout Error", GlobalLocalization.GetString("MonerisCheckoutError"), true));
                return false;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public override bool Rollback(OrderTaskContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override Task Clone()
    {
        return new StartMyPaymentMethodCheckout();
    }

    public override string TaskId()
    {
        return "E9B1A204-7C61-4664-A043-81BF43E24251";
    }

    public override string TaskName()
    {
        return "Start My ckout";
    }
}
```

doesnt redirect to google.com

**--Add New** 
why this code has not been overriden:

```
namespace MyCompany.MyPaymentMethod
{
    public class MyCustomWorkflowFactory : WorkflowFactory
    {
        protected override Task[] LoadThirdPartyCheckoutSelectedTasks()
        {
            return new Task[]
            {           
                new StartMyPaymentMethodCheckout()
            };
        }
    }
}
```

i have checked both inheritance  `public class MyCustomWorkflowFactory : WorkflowFactory` and `public class MyCustomWorkflowFactory : dnnWorkflowFactory` but none of them overiden on `protected virtual Task[] LoadThirdPartyCheckoutSelectedTasks()` , problem is there , I think !

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint in your StartMyPaymentMethodCheckout() method and Submitted the order at Checkout?  And the breakpoint does not get executed?

Comment: Does anyone have enough rep to tag this with e-commerce too?

Comment: `e-commerce` tag added , yes i have add breakepoint on `StartMyPaymentMethodCheckout()` and submite the order checkout

Answer (score 3):

Great question... Generally, if your breakpoint isn't getting hit, it's because you either haven't yet selected it yet in the Admin > Extensibility area, your code isn't yet deployed to where you're testing, or your code isn't following the prescribed pattern ([all noted in the documentation](https://hotcakescommerce.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204725949-Example-Action-Delegate-Pipeline-Integration-Project)).

[image]

Oh, and always make sure your web.config file is set to allow debugging like this.

```
<compilation debug="true" strict="false" targetFramework="4.0">
```

Comment: check out integration is empty and just have `no-integration' item, i will check `Action Delegate Pipeline Integration Project`

Comment: added more mistake on question , plz see it and tell the solution . in original sample it has been inheritance from `dnnWorkflowFactory` is that true ?!

Comment: I think the biggest issue here is that you're not even able to debug, right? That needs to be addressed before any other suggestions are valid.

Comment: no! break point hits on "MethodSettings" exp : `get { return GetSettingOrEmpty("Pin"); }`(whene loading payment method list) but not hits on `StartMyPaymentMethodCheckout` class , 100% problem is `MyCustomWorkflowFactory : WorkflowFactory` that woldnt be overriden. it seems that workflow go to run another methods.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't already, you may want to check out the detailed documentation for deployment at https://hotcakescommerce.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204725899-Custom-Payment-Method-Example

Comment: i have checked , may be problem is `WorkFlow` integration. that has not been explain there on `custome` payment method

Comment: `protected override Task[] LoadThirdPartyCheckoutSelectedTasks()` on sample didnt effect on workflow (or didnt overriden)